# How to suppress compiler warnings en masse in Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, gcc, llvm

Within several projects, I am using 3rd party code that produce more than a few compiler warnings. I obviously do not want to go through and modify code of actively updated 3rd party projects.

This leaves me with a lot of unnecessary warnings that drown out warnings in ***MY*** code.

I have used some compiler flags to suppress specific warnings on a per file basis, but that is much too tedious for open source code with 10-20 .m files.

Is there a way all warnings by Xcode group or file path? Or does somebody have a better suggestion?

(FYI: I am using the LLVM 1.5 compiler)

Comment: It looks like Mahmoud Khalifa answered your question to the best of Xcode's abilities. Otherwise, it looks like you need to file a RADAR. Please provide the RADAR number so others can ask for it when they come across this thread.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, XCode 3.x seems to only show the warnings for files that have actually been compiled in the most recent build, so if you build the project, modify a single file and then build the project again, you'll only see the warnings for the modified file. I generally find this to do more harm than good (especially since in Objective-C it's only a warning to call a selector that doesn't exist!) — and thankfully it's fixed in XCode 4 — but in your case in might be useful.

However, for various reasons you might want to consider putting the third-party code into a Framework. This wouldn't automatically suppress the warnings (although it might make it easier to suppress them) but it would mean that the third-party code was compiled into a library and therefore wasn't part of your normal compile cycle.

Comment: Using a framework (static lib on the iphone) may be my best hope as you said. I suppose that isn't too much trouble, and should solve the issues. My only problem with that technique, is that if there is a problem, I no longer have source code to look at. This is more a problem of having cake and eating it, or something to that effect…

Comment: Whether Xcode shows results from the last build or all builds is a setting in the Build Results window. I have mine set to All Builds and my Xcode preferences set to not stop on errors, so that a single build of a fresh project tells me all the warnings and errors it has.

Comment: The latest results is really the only solution that kinda works. It is just that sometimes real warnings still slip by if I miss them on the first "fresh" build.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off warnings on a per file basis is super simple. All that is required is a compiler flag. Here’s the step by step process.

1. Open the Project Navigator in Xcode
2. Click on the Project icon at the very top of the navigator
3. In the resulting detail pane select the target that you are working
   with
4. Select “Build Phases”
5. Expand “Compile Sources”
6. In the list locate the file that you’re interested in
7. Double click the column under the “Compiler Flags” column next to
   your file
8. Add a -w to the resulting dialog
9. Click “Done”
10. Build your now warnings free project

here is the reference link 
http://blog.bluelightninglabs.com/2011/12/suppressing-xcode-warnings-on-a-per-file-basis/

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not the easier solution, but you could go through these third-party libraries and fix their warning-causing bugs and submit patches. Then, the warnings go away, the bugs are fixed, and everybody gets to enjoy both improvements.

(How many warnings you'll be able to squash this way will depend on what they are: Deprecated-API warnings may be unavoidable if the library needs to support an older version of Mac OS X or iOS where the now-deprecated APIs were the only way.)

Comment: You are right, fixing the warnings is the obvious solution. I have done this in a couple open source projects, but due to time constraints, I can't fix warnings in every open source project I use. It would be ideal to treat the code I do not have time to fix as a "black box". And for some projects, as you mentioned, deprecated calls run amuck.